Protejer archivo conexion base datos php
Tengo un archivo llamado redireccion.php que recibe parámetros, redirije y envía datos a un archivo que conecta con la base datos.
El asunto está en que redireccion.php envía los parámetros con
exec("php guardar.php '$pub' '$sub' '$idVideo' '$url' '$country' '$device' '$browser' '$network' '$creativo' >/dev/null 2>&1 &");

Funciona bien, guardar.php los recibe bien.
El problema es que no se como evitar que guardar.php sea accedido dese la url, porque cualquiera que cargue el archivo guardar.php me genera un registro en la base datos.
Lo que trato es poder enviar esos datos desde redireccion.php a guardar.php, pero que guardar.php solo pueda ser accedido desde redireccion.php.

aca el TOC me pregunta por qué un exec? pero bueno aprovechando eso ponele un if (!defined('STDIN')) {die();} al principio del php y eso hace que solo se ejecute desde cli ( como con exec por ejemplo). o una forma mas acotada fijate que te tira la función php_sapi_name() desde dentro de guardar.php asi lo fijas a ese exec

por novato hermano jajaj

mmm... llámame tonto... pero no entiendo el porque quieres ejecutar un archivo PHP con exec cuando lo usual es hacerlo con ajax o bien, como creo que es tu caso, simplemente haciendo un include() de dicho archivo y de ahí pasarle o recuperar los datos.  Como no sabemos el contenido de guardar.php no sabemos si ese código completo se podria optimizar o enfocar de otra forma menos invasiva con el sistema. Te recuerdo que muchos hostings limitan el acceso a funciones potencialmente peligrosas, como exec() y eso puede bloquear su ejecución si lo subes a ellos.

je.. y si... supongo que lidiar con el array de los $argv puede ser un ejercicio para lograr un include o pastearle el code al redireccion

... cualquiera que cargue el archivo guardar.php me genera un registro en la base datos. Lo que ocurre aquí es un problema de enfoque. Hagas lo que hagas, o metas donde metas el archivo, cualquiera con más o  menos habilidades podrá acceder a él, mandarle datos y crear o modificar registros en la base de datos. Si quieres limitar el acceso tendrás que implementar un sistema de autenticación, mediante usario / contraseña, tokens de acceso, claves de API u otro. Quienes tengan esas credenciales podrán operar sobre ese archivo y quienes no las tengan no podrán hacerlo.

Como ya dijeron, sin todo el contexto solo podemos comentar más no responder. Pero a mi (que no me gusta complicarme) se me ocurre una idea, eso si, para responderte me gustaría saber todo el contenido de redireccion.php. Ahora que, si la una línea que importa de ese archivo es la del envío de los parámetros no hay problema, puedo responder igual, tu me dices.

Esto no tiene sentido ...
